# ImportError: cannot import name 'weight_as_number' from 'matplotlib.font_manager' ERROR on Kivy Matplotlib backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

When I import the garden.matplotlib package i recive a error mensage:
ImportError: cannot import name 'weight_as_number' from 'matplotlib.font_manager'

I used the Python in the Command Prompt to import step-by-step. I find a error in the garden.matplotlib import line.

System: Windows 10, Python 3.7.0, Kivy 1.10.1

```
>>> import matplotlib
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.

>>> matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')

>>>from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg

[INFO ] [Logger ] Record log in C:\Users\user.kivy\logs\kivy_18-10-03_7.txt
[INFO ] [Kivy ] v1.10.1
[INFO ] [Python ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
module = self.system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\garden_init.py", line 100, in load_module
return self.load_module(fullname, moddir)
File "D:\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\garden_init.py", line 104, in _load_module
('', '', imp.PKG_DIRECTORY))
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 245, in load_module
return load_package(name, filename)
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 217, in load_package
return load(spec)
File "C:\Users\user.kivy\garden\garden.matplotlib_init.py", line 1, in
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy import FigureCanvasKivy,
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\user.kivy\garden\garden.matplotlib\backend_kivy.py", line 257, in
from matplotlib.font_manager import weight_as_number
ImportError: cannot import name 'weight_as_number' from 'matplotlib.font_manager' (D:\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy only supports the older versions of matplotlib. They removed the weight_as_number function somewhere after matplotlib==2.1.x, so if you are running the latest (3.0.0) it won't work.

Try using matplotlib==2.1.2 (I am currently on this version, and can confirm weight_as_number is still present)

Comment: I do the downgrade to matplotlib 2.2.2 and everything is fine. Thanks